# Why does fgets() return a pointer to the newly filled char array?

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I can use fgets in the following way:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
  return 1;

char line[50];
fgets(line, 50, fp);

// do more stuff
```

This fills `line` as expected with chars from the file, so why does `fgets()`
need to return a pointer to `line`? `line` now contains the data I needed so what use is it returning a pointer to it?

Comment: I'm guessing for syntactic sugar reasons; you can use it as a parameter to other calls. Also if the parameter to `fgets` is a complicated pointer arithmetic expression, you only have to do it once.

Comment: Several standard functions are... curious about their return value. `strcat()`, for example, could be much more useful if it returned the *end* of the new string instead of the start, which you "know" about anyway. (Not to get me started about the truly useless functions like `strncpy()`.) You could possibly come up with some convoluted example where it might be useful, but usually, "it just is" must suffice. ;-) They were implemented, they were codified in the standard, and no-one in their right mind would try to change them after that.

Comment: The now obsolescent `gets` returned a pointer, so my guess is that `fgets` did it for the same reason. What would you expect it to return, if anything at all?

Comment: How do yo know it *worked* ? You see that check you make against `fp`? You're doing that is because it may *fail* to open your file, and in the process return NULL. And `fgets` returns NULL when it *fails* as well. Similar checks should be on *all* your IO operations.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I would of expected the return type to be an int, to indicate success / failure, not a char *

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand your point, but surely an int return would be better suited instead of char *

Comment: @CSStudent it would be a dreadful transition from `gets()` if that were the case.

Comment: @WhozCraig Being a beginner and just on the last few pages of K&Rs C programming language, there's no way I would of been aware of that transition. It makes sense though, you wouldn't want to drastically change the new function. So now the question is why did `gets() `return a `char *`? (I've not read over `gets()`).

Comment: @CSStudent I'd say it was because C programmers were lazy and liked using function results in compound expressions, but that would be somewhat akin to the pot calling the kettle black.

Comment: @DevSolar You may find this article explaining the purpose and usefulness of the [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html) function to be of interest. [`strncpy()`: Not a "safer" `strcpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: I was aware of that. (I actually implemented major parts of the Standard C Library in an open source project.) But outside of the very special case described in that article, `strncpy()` is certainly lacking, and definitely misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is documented in [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and in [POSIX fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) to do so.

Also, if you are sure that it does return a non-`NULL` pointer (i.e. that it does not fail), you might use its result as argument to some other function. I think it is a mistake to not test it.

BTW, I generally recommend using the newer [POSIX getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) which is able to deal with arbitrarily long lines (as long as resources permit it) -and returning on success the line length.

Comment: I have found, in the past, that man pages tend to be not very reliable (*cough*) when it comes to what is language standard, what is POSIX, and what is just the way it is done in Linux. That's why I use to add a caveat when they are referred to in a "the standard says so" context. ;-) +1 anyway for "because that's what it's defined to return".

Answer (score 1):

Because it had to return something to indicate errors. And at the time of its creation, returning a pointer smoothed transition from `gets`. It was written by programmers to be programmers friendly :-)

Comment: I wish I was around to see C develop so I could better understand some confusing aspects of it that have descended from the old days.

Comment: @CSStudent: You must understand that the standard library of C (and C++ as well) was not designed in a lab. People used the new language to get work done, created libraries, and some time afterwards, certain functions were made "standard" -- in the way they were implemented already, so that existing software would not become broken. These languages "grew", and not everything that grows naturally grows as our engineering mindset would like to have it, given a couple of decades' hindsight. As for the language proper, [this](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) is a good read.

Comment: @DevSolar I see, and thanks for the link, that will be an interesting read.

Comment: @OP, "I wish I was around to see C develop".  Careful what you wish for or some genie will come around and "poof" - you are now 40 years older.

Answer (score 0):

It returns NULL on EOF or error, so it gives you an easy way to detect success or failure on a call:

```
if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fp ))
{
  // do something with line
}
else
{
   // read failed
}
```

Why a pointer as opposed to an integer value?  As others have mentioned, `gets` returned a pointer value, so this made it easy to replace any existing `gets` calls (although the newline semantics are different, so it wasn't a totally painless change).

Why did `gets` return a pointer?  That's a question for Dennis Ritchie; unfortunately, he's no longer in a position to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fgets()` return value to distinguish expects results from others.

`char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);` returns either `s` or `NULL`.
When an end-of-file condition occurs (EOF) or an I/O Error occurs, `NULL` is returned.

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {  // best to use sizeof buffer @John Bode
  // do more stuff
}
else {
  // Handle EOF/IO errors.
  // In typical practise, only 1 of these 2 conditions are true.
  if (ferror(fp)) Handle_IOError();
  if (feof(fp)) Handle_EOF();
}
```